# Parse weird bug in Swift that causes ACL write permissions to change to an objectId

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2

First of all, this is how my parse table looks like after inserting a row to **riderRequest** table. After inserting, my ACL for Public Write defaults to the objectId of the **User** table.

**riderRequest** table
[image: riderRequest table]

**User** table
[image: User table[2]]

So this is my code that inserts the new row into my **riderRequest** table.

```
var riderRequest = PFObject(className: "riderRequest")
        riderRequest["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
        riderRequest["location"] = PFGeoPoint(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

        riderRequest.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
            if(success)
            {
                self.callUberButton.setTitle("Cancel Uber", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
            else
            {
                self.displayAlert("Could not call uber", message: "Please try again later")
            }
        }
```

My code has nothing to do with modifying the value of ACL.
I cant seem to figure this out, why is the ACL value modified?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: did you create a default ACL ?

Comment: my default acl looks like this        `let defaultACL = PFACL();`

       `defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)`

        `PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser:true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your AppDelegate. There's most likely a default ACL and it will look something like this

```
// Enable public read access by default, with any newly created PFObjects belonging to the current user
let defaultACL: PFACL = PFACL()
defaultACL.publicReadAccess = true
PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser: true)
```

Comment: my default ACL code in my AppDelegate looks like this `let defaultACL = PFACL();`
        `defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)`

        `PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser:true)`

Comment: I read up the parse documentation on default ACL, do you I `setPublicReadAccess(true)` and `setPublicWriteAccess(true)` when inserting new rows into my riderRequest table?

Comment: That's the exact same thing but with an out-of-date Parse SDK version. `setPublicReadAccess` was changed to be a property, as in my example, in the most recent version. Nevertheless, that is what's causing you to have public read access but only the current user can write. If you want to have public read ***and public write***, comment those 3 lines out. Parse defaults to public read and write

Comment: @SwiftEveryday that's entirely up to you and what you would like to accomplish. Typically, you don't want other people to be able to modify each other's objects, which means public read and private write (for the user). If you want public read and write, you can either comment out the defaultACL code in your app delegate or manually set the object's ACL to public read/write as you mentioned

Comment: I see, I will keep that in mind. Thank you so much for your help and advice, it really speeds up my learning process having someone experienced like you to guide me.

Comment: @SwiftEveryday absolutely! happy to help keep up the good work :)