# iOS Swift 3 Deleting a row from TableView Using Parse

Tags: parse-platform, swift3, xcode8, ios10, delete-row

I am building an iOS app and I am trying to delete a row from the UITableView. I am also using Parse as the mobile-backend of the app. Here is code for the delete method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Receipts")
        let currReceipt = receipts[indexPath.row]
        query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: currReceipt.objectId!)
        query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.createAlert(title: "Oops! Something went wrong number 1!", message: "We could not delete the receipt")
                print("THERE WAS AN ERROR DELETING THE OBJECT")
            }else{
                for object in objects!{
                    self.receipts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    object.deleteInBackground()
                    self.table.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Just to clarify, there will only be one receipt in the database with any given "objectId", so the query.findObjectsInBackground should only be returning a single object.

When I try to delete a row in the simulator, I get the error "Object not found" even though I can see that the object exists in the database. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
Found my solution after a long time looking. For anyone interested, it had to do with the default ACL values for Read and Write permissions. Here is the link to the answer: [Parse weird bug in Swift that causes ACL write permissions to change to an objectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926827/parse-weird-bug-in-swift-that-causes-acl-write-permissions-to-change-to-an-objec)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a typo, but why do you have ! in this line?

```
query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: currReceipt.objectId!)
```

Comment: When there is no "!" I get the warning that the "Expression [is] implicitly coerced from 'String?' to Any"

Comment: Found my solution after several days of searching... In case you were interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926827/parse-weird-bug-in-swift-that-causes-acl-write-permissions-to-change-to-an-objec